# Ruby - Invoking a class from a CONSTANT that contains the class name

Tags: ruby

I have a class that calls different suppliers to find if an item is available. How do I execute the class that each constant returns?

```
class ItemProvider

   ADAPTER_ONE = Providers::ItemFromSupplierOne
   ADAPTER_TWO = Providers::ItemFromSupplierTwo

   def get_item(item)
     id = ItemDetail.new(item)
     %w(ADAPTER_ONE ADAPTER_TWO).each do |provider| 
         item_detail = provider.new(id)
         break if item_detail.valid?
     end
   item_detail
end
```

Comment: Like you're doing. You're not just referencing the class name, it's the class itself.

Comment: @DaveNewton - How do I reference the class name. When I print the value of provider, it just says ADAPTER_XXX.

Comment: You're making an array of strings. Put them in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't making an array that contains the constants' values; you're making an array with the strings "ADAPTER_ONE" and "ADAPTER_TWO". The `%w()` syntax always makes an array of strings — it doesn't resolve variable names.

What you want is to change your `get_item` code to something like this:

```
def get_item(item)
  id = ItemDetail.new(item)
  [ADAPTER_ONE, ADAPTER_TWO].each do |provider| 
    item_detail = provider.new(id)
    break item_detail if item_detail.valid?
  end or nil # break automatically makes the block return the value you break with
end
```

As an aside, personally, I think I'd rewrite it like this:

```
def get_item(item)
  id = ItemDetail.new(item)
  [ADAPTER_ONE, ADAPTER_TWO].map {|provider| provider.new(id) }.find &:valid?
end
```

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. Thanks @Chuck. I also like how you wrote refactored my code. Can I ask what the - .find &:valid? does here?

Comment: @learning_to_swim: The `&` operator sends `to_proc` to the symbol `:valid?`. The Symbol class implements `to_proc` as something like `proc {|obj, *args| obj.send(self, *args)}`. So it's equivalent to `find {|provider| provider.valid?}`, which returns the first provider that answers truthy to `valid?`.

Answer (score 1):

Yup you have an array of strings not constants but if you want to go down that road in using classes from strings well it will be nice if you look at http://blog.sidu.in/2008/02/loading-classes-from-strings-in-ruby.html#.UuGdmGQ1i2w .Maybe it is not directly related to your problem but it is a good read.

Comment: Thanks! I did not have to use strings, it was just my ignorance. Fixed it now with Chuck's comment above.